# Able to POST direct messages using Twitter's REST API, but trying to GET returns a 401 error

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to get direct messages working in my app. I'm able to POST DMs just fine, but when I try to GET them from the endpoint https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages.json it returns a 401 - Unauthorized. I don't really understand how I can be authorized to send DMs but not get ones sent to me.

Here's how I'm authenticating initially:

```
if Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session() == nil {
            Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion { session, error in
                if (session != nil) {
                    // successfully logged in, call loading functions 
                } else {
                    print("error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            // already logged in, call loading functions 
        }
```

Every time I make a request using the REST API, it begins with

```
if let userID = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()?.userID {
            let client = TWTRAPIClient(userID: userID)
```

The client is initialised the same way in both the POST and GET requests for DMs, yet the GET request fails.

As far as permissions go, I've checked that it has read/write/DM access according to Twitter, and successful requests return `"x-access-level" = "read-write-directmessages";`, so I think it's set properly.

I was concerned at one point that I might not be authenticating properly, since Twitter's documentation goes through the 3 step process for O-Auth and all I'm doing is telling the Twitter singleton to just log in... but I rationalised that away by assuming that those steps are all carried out in the logInWithCompletion function. And besides, if I wasn't authenticated properly I surely wouldn't be able to send DMs, right?

Any ideas on how I can fix this? I'm quite new so it may be something nice and simple! I've looked through some other questions, but they all seem to code the requests in full rather than using built-in methods like these - or have I got it all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it was a stupid problem - I left the parameters blank since they are all marked as 'optional' - as in, a dictionary of ["" : ""]. I just set the paramaters in the request to nil, and now it works.